# Dealing with nanosecond timestamp strings

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have some timestamps that have resolution down to nanoseconds. I would like to be able to parse the timestamps and create Javascript Date objects (or some extension or analogue thereof) so they can be sorted/added/subtracted, etc. ... But it appears the Javascript Date object does not go beyond milliseconds.

Is there a way to extend the Date object to store the extra precision? I've looked for existing libraries that do this but haven't located any so far.

To be clear I don't need to get nanoseconds from Date.now() ... I just need to be able to parse timestamp strings into objects that have the necessary precision.

JS environment is the browser (not Node.js).

Comment: is the intention to display the parsed date strings in a human readable list (pretty dates rather than timestamps)? or do you need the date object for something more complex? if not, could you not parse the date and append to the string the extra nano seconds, storing the original string in a `data` attribute?

Comment: @haxxxton yes I want to be able to take two lists of date objects and sort them chronologically, add or subtract deltas, etc. The deltas should all be in milliseconds, but being able to sort datetimes is the primary objective. I suppose some of it can be extended to an additional data property as you say, and I can extend a library like moment.js, but it is unfortunate to not find a library that seems to already have support. It seems the browser js environments are not able to create at nano-scale so that is probably the reason, but wish I could still work with parsed items at that scale.

Answer (score 3):

late to the party, but here's my 2 cents

## [javascript temporal proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal)

- also supports nano-seconds precision: see [Instant class](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/#sec-temporal-instant-objects)
- since this will be added as a native javascript feature, it's definitely the way to go
- the proposal is at [Stage 3](https://tc39.es/process-document/) (as of June 2022)
- there are some [polyfills](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal#polyfills) available (**alpha** versions as of June, 2022)

## [js-joda](https://github.com/js-joda/js-joda)

- supports nano-second precision: see [LocalTime class](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/class/packages/core/src/LocalTime.js%7ELocalTime.html)

Note:

- I think extending the Date object is not a good idea. e.g. you could add a microsecond property, etc., but this can cause issues with existing code
- e.g. that there are many libs that will internally create copies of a date. i.e.often with code like this: `if (value instance of Date) value = new Date(Date.valueOf())` - and then your microsecond field info is lost

Answer (score 0):

My naive solution to compare dates with nanoseconds in a ISO String timestamp (Date.toISOString()) is extracting the nanos from the string `.000000Z` and adding it to the milliseconds obtained from `getTime()`.

```js
function getNanoseconds(d) {
  var x1 = new Date(d),
    x1n = d.split('.')[1].split('Z')[0],
    x1n = Number(x1n).toString();
  x1t = x1.getTime() + parseInt(x1n)
  return x1t;
}

var d1 = '2023-03-03T18:55:38.000975Z'
d2 = '2023-03-03T18:55:38.000310Z'
console.log(`${d2} < ${d1}`)
console.log(`using getTime: ${(new Date(d2)).getTime()} < ${(new Date(d2)).getTime()} ${(new Date(d1)).getTime() < (new Date(d1)).getTime()}`)
console.log(`using getNanoseconds: ${getNanoseconds(d2)} < ${getNanoseconds(d1)} ${getNanoseconds(d2) < getNanoseconds(d1)}`)
```